# How to disable PDF print options using JWebBrowser

Tags: java, swing

I'm using `The DJ Project` to open `PDF` files into `JFrame`. 
Using the next code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(panel);
        JWebBrowser browser = new JWebBrowser();

        browser.setBarsVisible(false);
        browser.setStatusBarVisible(false);
        browser.print(false);

        browser.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        panel.add(browser);
        browser.navigate("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\acta.pdf");
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
```

And is loading the PDF file, but I want to disable the next options:

[image]

The `print` and `Save` option. I know that is rendering over a Web Browser.
Is posible remove those options using java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I already found, is disabling all the components and interactions, with:

```
browser.getNativeComponent().setEnabled(false)
```

Or disabled all the right clicks, for example:

```
webBrowser.executeJavascript("document.oncontextmenu = function functionName(){ return false; }");
```